# How come the snake moves with these codes?

Tags: java, game-development

I just watched a youtuber make a snake game and I cannot understand how these codes make the snake move. The x[] here is the x coordinate while the y[] is the y coordinate. The youtube didn't really explain much so I hope I can get answers here.

```
for(int i=bodyParts;i>0;i--) {
        x[i]=x[i-1];
        y[i]=y[i-1];
    }
    switch(direction) {
        case 'U':
            y[0] = y[0]-UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        case 'D':
            y[0] = y[0]+UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        case 'L':
            x[0] = x[0]-UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        case 'R':
            x[0] = x[0]+UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share more information ? probably x[0] = x[0]+UNIT_SIZE; here coordinate is increasing so snake is moving.

Comment: `x` and `y` is space coordinate. When you click on `U/Up`, `D/Down`, `L/Left`, `R/Right` `x` and `y` coordinate changes. It is how snake is moving through.

Comment: Oh okay, I think I understand now. Thank you both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
for(int i=bodyParts;i>0;i--) {
        x[i]=x[i-1];
        y[i]=y[i-1];
    }
```

In this, the body part of the snake `x[i]` moves 1 space backward which will show the snake moving.

```java
    switch(direction) {
        case 'U':
            y[0] = y[0]-UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        case 'D':
            y[0] = y[0]+UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        case 'L':
            x[0] = x[0]-UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        case 'R':
            x[0] = x[0]+UNIT_SIZE;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

You haven't provided many contexts here but I'm assuming when its case `'U'` the first body part of the snake will equal to itself subtracted with the unit size you have given. Vice versa for case 'D' and similar for right and left.

Answer (score 1):

We don't have much context here to go on, but I'm going to guess (`x[0]`, `y[0]`) are the coordinates of the snake's head, and (`x[i]`, `y[i]`) the coordinates of each of the remaining body parts of the snake.

The body of the switch statement adjusts the coordinates of the head according to the direction to move in. For example, to move down (`case 'D'`), the y-coordinate `y[0]` is increased by `UNIT_SIZE` in `y[0] = y[0]+UNIT_SIZE;`.

---

The for loop iterates over each body part of the snake, moving it to where the next body part previously was. For example, if your snake was

```
  0 1 2 3
        4
        5 6
```

where `0` is the head, and were to move left, the snake would then become

```
0 1 2 3 4
        5
        6
```

where `2` has moved to where `1` was, `3` has moved to where `2` was, and so on. This is why the loop

```java
for (int i = bodyParts; i > 0; i--) {
    x[i] = x[i-1];
    y[i] = y[i-1];
}
```

moves the `i`-th body part to where the `i-1`-th body part previously was.

Comment: Oh that's why it moves. Thanks